# Rivkah not giving water to the men traveling with Eliezer?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, genesis-bereishith, parashat-chaye-sara

In Parshat Chayei Sarah, we all are familiar with the episode of Rivkah imenu offering water to Eliezer first then to the camels.

However, the Torah doesn't record Rivkah giving water to the men traveling with Eliezer.

Why does the Torah not record this detail and why were these men traveling with Eliezer so absent from the story until verse 24:32?

Comment: I would say it’s implied that the men were also given water by Rivkah, but the main emphasis is that she gave to the camels because that was the whole test- whether her chesed extended to the animals or not. As for why the men are even mentioned in pasuk 32, Haktav V’Hakabbalah says that Laban and Betuel initially thought Eliezer was just another slave amongst the rest, but then after they realized he was distinguished from the other slaves. So the other slaves are mentioned here to make that point